# Implement database structure with isVisible value for each column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures

I worked a lot with DBs but never came to design one.
I am struggling about the structure, on one of the most common table, *personal data*:

The main table is called *user* with few column. 
Then i have *General* which will have (id, userRef, name, surname, age, email, genderRef, phonenumber, addressRef) and so on..

The problem is that each of this value/column, needs to have a **Visible** value related.

I don't think is a good practice to put everything in the same table like (name, nameVisible, age, ageVisible). And neither to create a table for each of them..

Could you please advice any better solution? 
thanks.

Comment: Please explain how the "visible" column is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion make another table where you can create three columns like below

```
  table_name,column_name,is_visible
```

so from this table you will control which column will be visible or which will not

Comment: this is perfectly fine, but I guess this should be handled in application layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control visibility of a column, then I would recommend using views.

If the "is visible" flag is intended over the entire table, then just create the view that you want:

```
create view visible_personal_data as
    select  -- visible columns here
    from personal_data;
```

If you want this flag to be specific to each row/column combination, I would recommend storing it in the data . . . but still using a view:

```
create view visible_personal_data as
    select (case when userRef_isvisible then userRef end) as userRef,
           (case when name_isvisible then name end) as name,
           . . .
    from personal_data;
```

You can set access so users only have access to the views, but not the underlying tables.  That way, people only see what they are supposed to see.